# How to pass parameter to Converter<DataRow, T>?

Tags: c#, list, dataset

I have a generic method to Convert dataset to list.

```
public static List<T> ConvertDS<T>(DataSet ds, Converter<DataRow, T> converter)
        {
            return
                (from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                 select converter(row)).ToList();
        }
```

but i don't know how to pass parameter to "converter" in the above function.
I have list AddressInfo like this

```
List<AddressInfo> lstAddressInfo = new List<AddressInfo>();

lstAddressInfo =ConvertDS(ds,"What to send here")
```

Comment: Is `converter` an instance or a type?

Comment: So the line `converter(row)` is just a cast? It's not a function call?

Comment: [`Converter<TIn, TOut>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) is a delegate defined in the base class library. `converter` is an instance of the delegate, passed as an argument to `ConvertDS`.

Comment: @shambulator ah, was assuming this was custom code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `Converter<TIn, TOut>` is a delegate, then the following should work:

```
lstAddressInfo =ConvertDS(ds, (row) => {
    return new AddressInfo
    {
        Property1 = row["PropertyA"],
        ...
    };
});
```

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj no the delegate takes in a `DataRow` and returns `T` which in your case is `AddressInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lstAddressInfo =ConvertDS(ds, convert)

public static AddressInfo convert (DataRow data)
{
 //function converting data
}
```

You need to specify method converting `DataRow` to `AddressInfo` and pass it to new `Converter`

Edited as shambulator and James suggested

Comment: While your answer will work, it uses what I would consider outdated C# syntax. Since (I believe) C# 2.0, you can omit `new DelegateType(...)` and just use the method name: `ConvertDS(ds, convert)`. For current versions of C#, you can use lambdas, as in James's answer.

Comment: @wudzik you don't need the `(datarow) => convert(datarow)`, you just need `convert`. At the minute you have an anonymous delegate which calls a named method...which is pointless. Either use the anonymous one or pass the named method.